# Android/iPhone mobile payments

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, payment

I am developing some kind of digital membership cards system that needs to replace current plastic one. I would need to provide the user with the possibility to buy membership card directly within the application and therefore need some mobile payment option. I am developing this for both Android and iOS platforms so some web service or API would be the best solution. I have looked a bit around and the things I have found are:

Paypal Mobile: https://personal.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/mobile_payments

DIBS Mobile: http://www.dibspayment.com/products/internet/add-on_packages/mobile/

Just push me in the right direction or give me some idea :)

Regardz,
Mladjo

Answer (score 2):

Both Google and Apple require you to use their own payment systems within apps. So:

1. You will not be able to use a common payment system for both Android and iPhone.
2. While Google does not allow third party payment systems, Apple at the moment kinda tolerates them, but requires you to also use their iTunes in-app payment system, so you will have to implement both.

Comment: Regarding apple. You are not allowed to use IAP for goods or services used outside of the app. So this won't be a problem. There is no need to give apple 30% if you book a flight within an app, as there is no need if you buy something in the ebay app. All the recent fuss is about ebook stores that use the ebooks inside the app `11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. OP is talking about "digital membership cards". I'm really not sure where they fit in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the response from PP support team regarding Android distribution agreement and 3rd party payment processor implementation.

> So android cannot prevent you from
>   selling in app purchases of any type,
>   weather digital or otherwise. The
>   distribution Agreement from the
>   Android Marketplace does however
>   mention the following:
>
> "However, if you want to collect fees
>   after the free trial expires, you must
>   collect all fees for the full version
>   of the Product through the Payment
>   Processor on the Market"
>
> This would mean that you must use the
>   Android Marketplace payment processor
>   to upgrade from a free trial. As your
>   application does not technically fall
>   under this category you would not be
>   breaking the Distro agreement. To be
>   100% sure on this you would need to
>   contact Android about this. Also
>   please note that the distribution
>   agreement does not extend past the
>   Android Marketplace, for example the
>   AppBrain market is not effected by
>   this.
>
> I would like to point out that PayPal
>   have approved a large number of
>   applications for use of the MPL that
>   are live on the Android Marketplace at
>   the moment.

Comment: Damjan, How are these applications that are using the MPL allowed to sell in the Android Marketplace?

Comment: They're not. You have to use android in-app billing.